# How can I restrict the Applovin appopen ads showing while trying to login with Apple Sign in

Tags: ios, applovin

I am showing appopen ads in my app. But the app showing the Applovin AppOpen ads when I am trying to login with the Apple. How can I restrict such behaviour while logging in.

```
self.appOpenAd.delegate = self;
           [sdk initializeSdkWithCompletionHandler:^(ALSdkConfiguration *configuration) {
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   ALSdk *sdkm = [ALSdk shared];
                   sdkm.settings.muted = YES;
                   [strategy hideSplash];
                   [self goHome];
                   [self.appOpenAd loadAd];
                   dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 3 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                           [self showAdIfReady];
                   });

               });
           }];
```